# Find nullity of T

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V=\{P(x)|P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree
$\leq n$ with real cofficients} and $T:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m}$be
defined as $T\{P(x)\}=\{P(1),P(2),...........P(m)\}$.Determine the nullity
of $T$. i.e., $Dim\  N(T)=?$

$\boldsymbol{My}$ $\boldsymbol{Approach}$:
 If Degree of P(x)= n$\prec$m then nullity would be zero

If $n\geq m$ then $P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3).............(x-m).P(x)$ will
belong to $N(T).$

But I can not conclude the dimension of $N(T).$

$\boldsymbol{Internet}$ $\boldsymbol{Reference}$: On internet I found
somehow same problem but there $P(x)$ was suggested to be $P(x)=f(x)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)......(x-m).$
where $f(1)\neq 1,f(2) \neq 2......................f(m) \neq m.$

I don't know why use $f(x)$?

Comment: It is very hard to read your question with the formatting you currently have. Have a look at this guide https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: my formatting is latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $n$ and $m$ for the sake of understanding, say $n=7, m=3$. So your aim is to find all polynomials $P(x)$ of degree at most seven with roots at $x=1,2,3$.
S0, $P(x)$ should be of the form $f(x)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$. The degree condition means $f(x)$ can be any polynomial of degree at most 4. So $P(x)$ should be 
a linear combination of $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, $x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, $x^2(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, $x^3(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ and $x^4(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$. As these are all of different degrees they are linearly independent and hence $N(T)$ has dimension 4. In general $\dim N(T)=n-m$.

Comment: the idea looks very much general.i dont know specific conditions but often i see it.A linear tranformation from R^3 to R^2 have nullity 3-2=1 .i just want you to enlighten me a bit more